# Difference between Web.config and App.config

Tags: vb.net, wcf

What is the difference between a Web and App .config file in a WCF Service.

From what I have found so far you can use either to specify the Service Settings but is there any need to use one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is hosted with `IIS` , `web.config` is there.

If your application is `standalone` ,  `app.config` is there.

We use `Web.Config`  where `asp.net` web projects or `web services` are there and ,

`App.Config` is used where `Windows Forms`, `Windows Services`, `Console Apps` and `WPF applications` are there.

Answer (score 0):

you can read more about it here in the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx

Difference between Web.config and Machine.config:

The settings made in the Web.config file are applied to that particular web application only whereas the settings of Machine.config file are applied to the whole asp.net application.

Web.config file Setting of asp.net all project Machine.config are setting of server setting.

Web config will be for that particular aplln whereas the Machine .config will for the whole machine.

Every ASP.NET application has a Web.config file . The settings specified in this will imply only to that application. Whereas Your System will have a Machine.config file in Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\CONFIG Folder which contains specifications and settings at a system level.

Web.config file is to override the settings from the Machine.config file. Machine.config file settings are applied to all the webapplications residing on the server while Web.config settings are application specific.

Machine. config is configuration file for all the application in the IIS. but Web.config is a configuration file for a application or folder.

Machine.config for machine level configuration. Web.config for a application/folder level configuration.

Comment: Machine.config - what is this?

Comment: machine.config is the top level one. It is applied to all sites running on that server. There are some settings which can only be configured in this .config file for security reasons (imagine if you had several different clients hosted on your server). Other settings can be overridden by web.config for example in an individual website.

Comment: Just ignore it :) I m just confusing u :)

Comment: Ok well I wasn't after the machine.config file only the app.config and the web.config. As this would change all the WCF Services I'm hosting all hell would break loose.

Comment: Look up the documnetation of the web and app config.